# how to get file information / search directories

Tags: c++, windows, file, io

I'm wondering how do you do stuff like gettling file information, searching through directories/subdirectories in c++? Is there a particular library that I should be looking at?

I'm seeing stuff like this in some examples:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

Not sure where they came from.. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm programming in Windows btw

Comment: What Operating System(s) are you using?  Please add that information to the question.

Comment: oh yes, sorry bout that, it's in windows

Answer (score 5):

[Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) comes to mind.

Comment: Seconded. This is a terrific cross-platform library.

Answer (score 4):

In windows you can use the Win32 API - FindFirstFile & FindNextFile for searching in folders, and various GetFileXXX calls.

See here for more info: [MSDN information on file APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MFC, see [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618(VS.80).aspx).  Even if you aren't, check out its implementation (if you are using Visual Studio and have installed the MFC source).

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ has no directory access functions. On Windows, your choice is between a cross platform library such as Boost, or use of the Windows native [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and associated functions.